# Mediawiki images 403 denied access

Tags: apache, permissions, mediawiki, angular2-directives

I have set up MediaWiki on Ubuntu 16 following [Wiki family drupal style sites](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family#Drupal-style_sites) and no matter what I do I get 403 forbidden on all images. That is, images do not show on the wiki, nor when directly navigated to in the URL.

The images directory is outside of the DocumentRoot.

Here is my Apache directives

```
DocumentRoot "/home/DOMAIN/public_html/mediawiki/mediawiki1.28"
ServerName en.DOMAIN.org
Alias /images "/home/DOMAIN/public_html/mediawiki/sites/images"
<Directory "/home/DOMAIN/public_html/mediawiki/mediawiki1.28">
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}//index.php [L]
## http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache
# Enable the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
# Short url for wiki pages
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]
# Redirect / to Main Page
RewriteRule ^/*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]
#
Options -Indexes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

(In the DocumentRoot and Directory paths symlinks are used, but I have changed to reflect the actual location)

Permissions of the Images directory:

`/home/DOMAIN/public_html/mediawiki/sites/images`
`drwxr-xr-x www-data  www-data  images`

All else is DOMAIN:DOMAIN

I have even ran `chmod -R 777 images` to test.

I have tried with other directories and files in the area where images dir is located, without any success, and that leads me to think that I cannot access *ANYTHING* outside of the DocumentRoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding

```
<Directory "/home/DOMAIN/public_html/mediawiki/sites/images">
allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
```